# Resizing matplotlib figure with set_fig(width/height) doesn't work

Tags: python, matplotlib

For some reason this code creates a figure that is only the standard size: it doesn't change the height or width (I chose widths and heights that are ludicrous to clearly illustrate the problem):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_figwidth(30)
fig.set_figheight(1)

print('Width: {}'.format(fig.get_figwidth()))

plt.show()
```

I'm running on OSX 10.10.4, Python 3.4.3, Matplotlib 1.4.3. (Installed via Macports.) Any ideas? What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like fig.set_figsize(30, 1, forward=True) works, but the forward=True keyword argument is necessary. If forward=False, or if left off, it doesn't work. It's a workaround I suppose: I can do fig.set_figsize(fig.get_width(), value) to set only one. But this is a workaround, I'd like to know why it doesn't work. Maybe I should file as a bug?

Comment: Does `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30,1))` work?

Comment: @N1B4 Yes, but I want to change the figure size after creation at the time of adding a colorbar. Basically, I want to programmatically expand the window when I create a colorbar so my figure still fits nicely inside the window, and I don't know at figure creation whether I will add a colorbar or not.

Comment: You could set the figure size at the end with `fig.set_size_inches(30,1)` and replace 30 or 1 with something new if a colorbar is included. Or more dynamically, first determine the figure size (e.g. `size = fig.get_size_inches()`) and adjust that as needed.

Comment: Whoops... I meant fig.set_size_inches... not set_figsize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not certain why those [documented functions](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html?highlight=figure#matplotlib.figure.Figure.set_figheight) don't work, but [they have been fixed](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/4677) for the next matplotlib release (>v1.4.3). As a workaround until the next release, replacing `set_figwidth` and `set_figheight` solves this problem.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
# Instead of set_figwidth(30)
fig.set_size_inches(30, fig.get_figheight(), forward=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: it doesn't changed for me at all

Comment: This is what I was looking for, It worked. I adjusted height to meet my requirements as well. `fig.set_size_inches(5, 15, forward=True)`

Answer (score 6):

The optional parameter `forward` propagates changes to the canvas in a GUI window that *already exists*.

[Documentation here:](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html?highlight=set%20size%20inches#matplotlib.figure.Figure.set_size_inches)

> optional kwarg `forward=True` will cause the canvas size to be automatically updated; e.g., you can resize the figure window from the shell

Using `Figure(figsize=(w,h))` also works.

## For Matplotlib 2.2.0 and newer

`forward=True` is the default for all three of [`set_figheight`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html?highlight=set%20size%20inches#matplotlib.figure.Figure.set_figheight), [`set_figwidth`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html?highlight=set%20size%20inches#matplotlib.figure.Figure.set_figwidth), and [`set_size_inches`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html?highlight=set%20size%20inches#matplotlib.figure.Figure.set_size_inches) (`set_size_inches` changes both height and width simultaneously).

## For Matplotlib 1.5.0

`forward=True` must be specified explicitly as it is `False` by default. (In Matplotlib 2.0.0, the default is changed to `True` *only* for `set_size_inches`).

## For Matplotlib 1.4.3 and older

`forward` is only supported by `set_size_inches`.

[`set_figheight`](https://matplotlib.org/1.4.3/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.set_figheight) and [`set_figwidth`](https://matplotlib.org/1.4.3/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.set_figwidth) do not support this argument, so it is a bit difficult to only change a single dimension of a pre-created GUI.